# iOS reset device orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c

Consider the following case:
the iPhone is in portrait mode.
I do this:

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
```

and lock my device orientation in landscape mode. So I can turn my phone in any direction and the orientation stays the same. Great;

Then I unlock orientation like this:

```c
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
```

and device orientation will follow iPhone physical orientation as desired.

Now the problem comes with this case only:
I set the orientation to landscape (`UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`) and keep the phone vertically (in portrait mode). The screen rotates as desired. Then I set orientation back to `UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown` without moving the phone... the screen stays in the landscape until I physically turn the phone horizontally and then back to a vertical position.
So I need to tell the iPhone, other than unlocking the orientation, update screen orientation to device physical orientation (as happens automatically in Android for example).
Is this possible?
Finally: this happens at least on the iPhone simulator. I currently haven't a real device to test with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need subscribe to orientation change, and restore orientation when you need it. Here is full example:

```c
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL fixedOrientation;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIDeviceOrientation lastOrientation;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.fixedOrientation = false;
    [UIDevice.currentDevice beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceOrientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)deviceOrientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notif {
    self.lastOrientation = [UIDevice.currentDevice orientation];
}

- (IBAction)buttPressed {
    UIDeviceOrientation last = [UIDevice.currentDevice orientation];

    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
    [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
    self.fixedOrientation = true;

    self.lastOrientation = last;
}

- (IBAction)butt2Pressed:(id)sender {
    self.fixedOrientation = false;
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.lastOrientation];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
    [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (self.fixedOrientation) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}


@end
```

**EDIT:** `requires fullscreen` option shall be selected for both iPhone and iPad for this to work otherwise `deviceOrientationChanged` will never be called.

Comment: That's great! Thank'you very much!

Comment: ...mmm I still have a problem: device in portrait, press butt1, interface goes landscape, press butt2 (without moving the device), the interface stays in landscape. If I repeat the same procedure but I turn the device 360 deg before pressing butt2, then the interface goes back to portrait as desired. It seems that attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation does nothing if the device hasn't moved

Comment: On `buttPressed` I save current orientation in first line of code. Your scenario works fine with this code. Please, checkout your code.

Comment: Yes I save the value before forcing orientation and restore it just after that because the deviceOrientationChanged is called when calling attemptRotation... . My scenario is a bit more complex that this. However your solution works and was of a great help for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I have following example in Swift. Instead of using `UIDeviceOrientation` I found`UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation` to be more reliable. I have more detail example in [GitHub project](https://github.com/hadanischal/BusinessContacts/blob/development/BusinessContacts/Controller/ContactsViewController.swift)

**Declare**

```
var currentInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientation.unknown
```

**Update orientation**

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape {
            self.currentInterfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft
        } else {
            self.currentInterfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait
        }
        self.deviceDidRotate()
    })
}

private func deviceDidRotate() {
    //perform your action
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however according to Apple doc (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623026-statusbarorientation?language=objc) seems to be deprecated